# Пронумеровать столбец MySQL

Tags: mysqli, mysql

Здравствуйте, в этом деле новичок. Подскажите пожалуйста запрос, который пронумерует столбец.
Сейчас в нем все нули, а надо 1, 2, 3 ...

[image: img]

Спасибо!

Comment: http://www.sql.ru/forum/684431/faq-numeraciya-strok-i-drugie-voprosy-pro-ispolzovanie-peremennyh

Comment: Чета не выходит..

Такой запрос нумерует в разброс:

update 
   `xa8bh_jshopping_shipping_method`
set
   `ordering` =(select @a:= @a + 1 from (select @a:= 0) s)
order by 
   `ordering`

Comment: Что значит "в разброс"? В исходной картинке у Вас ordering = 0 для всех строк. Нафига Вам предложение ORDER BY ordering в UPDATE?

Comment: http://s020.radikal.ru/i719/1309/c1/cdd7d04a410e.png

Как будто этот столбец зависит от другого..

Comment: Вообщем вот так выходит:
http://s019.radikal.ru/i600/1309/9b/e3e751ac1283.png
Сделана сортировка по алфавиту, как выровнять номер строки, не сортируя названия?

Comment: А почему Вы не хотите их сортировать? В случае UPDATE ... ORDER BY name_ru-RU что получается?

Answer (score 1):

Вам скорее всего нужен автроинкремент. В своём инструменте посмотрите как его добавить. Это обычно в настройках таблицы, значение поля по умолчанию, AutoIncrement.

Comment: @dimka3210 Вы не прочитали вопроса. Строки уже есть, autoincrement влияет на добавление, если значение поля не задано.